# What is the difference in meaning between "I play" and "I do play"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, auxiliary-verbs

What is the difference between *I play* and *I do play*?

For example:

If someone were to ask to me, do you play soccer?

Answer (score 15):

In modern English, auxiliary 'do' is used in five cases:

1. Negative (obligatory for most verbs): "I don't like mushrooms".
2. Interrogative (obligatory for most verbs): "Do you like mushrooms?"
3. Emphatic: "Oh, you've done some cauliflower! I *do* like cauliflower!"
4. Contrastive (a special case of emphatic). "I don't like mushrooms. But I do like cauliflower".
5. Anaphoric for the main verb: "Do you like cauliflower?" "Yes, I do".

In older English, and some dialects, it may be used outside these cases, but not normally in modern standard dialects.

Answer (score 7):

If someone asks

> Do you play soccer?

it would be unnatural though correct to reply

> I play soccer.

Usually one would reply with one of the following.

> Yes, I do.
>
> No, I don't.

There is a situation in which one would use *do* followed by a verb, and that is for reasons of *emphasis*. For instance, if your girlfriend asks you

> Do you care about me at all?

you would reply

> I do care.

Comment: +1 - And if somebody asks you "do you play [footvolley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footvolley)?", you could answer "No, I don't. But I do play soccer". In this case, **do** is to emphasize that what you said about soccer is the opposite to what you said about footvolley (don't vs. do).

Comment: I removed my comment and added it back to be able to make a small edit - that's why it now appears after your comment.

Comment: But you could respond with "Yes, I play soccer", leaving out the *do*.