# 'Did see' and 'Saw'

Tags: word-choice, verbs, do-support

The blog post [here](http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/2011/06/isnt_this_just_the_cutest_thin.php) uses the title

> “Isn’t this just the cutest thing you
>   ever **did see**?”

I am sure this is correct, but my question is, but what difference it would have made had he used the following version instead:

> “Isn’t this just the cutest thing you
>   ever **saw**?”

Comment: "Isn't this just the cutest thing you have ever seen?"

Comment: @English_questionmark: I don't think *the cutest thing you have ever seen* is even in the running against *you ever did see*. If you're going to speak of cute things, you probably want to use 'cute' phrasing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference in meaning between "I play" and "I do play"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-i-play-and-i-do-play). I know there's a slight difference in that *"...you ever **did** see"* is a dated formulaic expression, but that's fully covered by @Peter Shor's answer here. Everything else is better covered by Colin Fine's answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a formulaic expression in English, going back quite a while, that goes "the xxxxxest  xxxx you ever did see. From Google books:

> 1666: the finest pile I ever did see — from Samuel Pepys' diary
>   1792: strangest reason perhaps you ever did or will hear
>   1799: the ugliest old creature I ever did see
>   1832: the highest tree prehaps you ever did see
>   1832: the drollest varmint perhaps you ever did see
>   1835: the primest piece you ever did see
>   1836: the most knowing-looking little bit of a horse you ever did see
>   1836: most genial islands you ever did see
>   1851: the greatest muss you ever did see
>   1866: we have got one of the gratis olde raskells for a Captain you ever did see
>   1884: the sickest little shaver you ever did see
>   1920: the best bunch of man-hunters you ever did see
>   1968: the biggest lock you ever did see
>   1973: [the cutest thing that I ever did see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Joker_%28song%29)
>   2000: the happiest child you ever did see

A substantial fraction of the Google hits for "you ever did see" follow this formula. My answer would be: there's no significant difference in meaning here; it's just an instance of this formula.

From Google books search, it appears to have increased in usage fairly abruptly in the 1830s. Did it really, and if so, where did this come from? The only thing that I can think of is the [children's song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_the_Green_Grass_Grew_All_Around). But there's no evidence this dates back to the 1830s.

Comment: It *is* a 'formulaic' usage, but I think the prevalence of the actual word *see* is mainly just because that's the most likely one to fit the context. *The strangest sound you ever did hear* simply doesn't get so many chances to be spoken, but it sounds fine to me. I agree though - the main associations are 'poetic' cum 'nursery rhyme/fairy story'. So - good question - who started it?

Comment: The [children's song](http://books.google.com/books?id=6tvfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA111&dq=tree+stood+newell&hl=en&ei=RPD_TYLjHM_3gAfJpfX1DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), despite what Wikipedia says, goes back to at least 1883.

Comment: This one is structurally the same format, from 1828, unless it really is Samuel Pepys words from 1665...http://books.google.com/books?id=4m8pAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA272&dq=%22ever+did+see%22&hl=en&ei=NvT_TY3BF4Wc-waMsdnyDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22ever%20did%20see%22&f=false

Comment: In the 1830's and the immediately following decades, the usages are predominantly American. This may have been around in American usage earlier, as I suspect the corpus of American writing may expand significantly sometime around then.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence uses a more informal, Southern United States syntax, so it has a different "flavor." For formal writing, the latter sentence feels more formal, professional, and grammatical. In terms of meaning, there is little real difference, even though the verb tenses are not the same.