# Difference between "does have" and "has"

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“did shoot” vs “shot”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot)
>   ['Did see' and 'Saw'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30686/did-see-and-saw)
>   [“I understand you” vs “I do understand you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42138/i-understand-you-vs-i-do-understand-you)
>   [What is the difference in meaning between “I play” and “I do play”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-i-play-and-i-do-play)

What is the difference between *does have* and *has*? For example, compare *she does have a car* and *she has a car*.

Answer (score 19):

Based on my understanding as a native speaker (London, England), normally you would say "she has a car."

However, if you want to emphasize that it's not true to say the she *does not* have a car, then you would say that she *does* have a car.

For example:

> How can Jane get there?
>   She has a car.

not:

> How can Jane get there?
>   * She does have a car.

But:

> Does Jane have a car?
>   Yes, she does.
>
> She doesn't have a van, but she does have a car.
>   (Also correct: She doesn't have a van, but she has a car.)

Comment: I feel your second boxed example is fine to say if someone wasn't too happy about Jane asking to be picked up, "does have" stressing that she should use it.

Comment: @Sancho   I'm not a native speaker, but if the exchange were as follows, I'd say that "does have" is necessary.  "It's not true, she doesn't have a car!"  "Oh yes, she does have a car, and a bike as well." As BDS pointed out earlier, you would use "do/does" in order to stress a concept. This could be done with other verbs as well, for example "I don't know who will win the match, but I do know who cannot win."

Comment: @Sancho: Good question. I can't think of one right now, would be interested to know if anyone else can. I think "She says she doesn't but really she does have a car" comes close, but it doesn't seem completely wrong to me with "really she has a car".

Comment: @jontyc: Good point. I think in that case you'd be suggesting that she might be hiding the fact that she has a car, or that she is hoping that someone had forgotten that she has a car, and so you want to emphasize that the claim that she *does not* have a car is wrong, even though it was never explicitly stated.

Comment: @bdsl  you're right, I keep forgetting that in comments you cannot move on to the next line...

Comment: @Sancho although your example with "she does have a car and a bike as well" sounds entirely natural and idiomatic, and probably the better choice, I don't think use of "she has a car" would seem wrong to me in that context either.

Comment: It's never really necessary, but it would sometimes be odd not to add the emphasis. "How is she going to get there when she doesn't have a car?" "But she *does* have a car!" You could also answer "But she *has* a car!"; it's perfectly grammatical, but it's not quite idiomatic.

Comment: What kind of car has she?

Answer (score 6):

In general, the difference between *has* and *does have* is simply that including the [modal auxiliary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) verb **do** adds emphasis (which can also be achieved by intonation alone, but let that pass for now).

Thus, *"She does have a car"* might validly be used in various contexts. For example

- **surprise** *the speaker didn't previously realise she had a car, and he's just seen her drive past*.
- **exasperation** *"We can't expect her to walk all the way to our house". "She does have a car!"*
- **refutation** *"She lost everything in the flood". "Not quite - she does have a car."*

etc., etc.

British speakers often use **get** as the auxiliary verb - ["She has got a car"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20does%20have%20a,he%20has%20got%20a&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) - again, adding emphasis.