# What is difference between "Environment does matter" & "Environment matters"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “does have” and “has”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64487/difference-between-does-have-and-has)
>   [“did shoot” vs “shot”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot)
>   ['Did see' and 'Saw'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30686/did-see-and-saw)
>   [“I understand you” vs “I do understand you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42138/i-understand-you-vs-i-do-understand-you)
>   [What is the difference in meaning between “I play” and “I do play”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-i-play-and-i-do-play)

Is there any specific scenario where the "Environment does matter" used ? Actually, its a tagline of a product.

Guys any ideas?