# "Which browsers do support this?" or "Which browsers support this?"

Tags: questions, do-support

What is the correct syntax:

- "Which browsers do support this?"
- "Which browsers support this?"

Comment: Both are correct in their own context, but the first implies emphasis: "Well, which browsers **do** support this, then?!" Context is important: what triggers this question?

Comment: Ok. There's not much context. I was just wondering if one of those was incorrect. I have the answer then. Thank you :)

Comment: ["Did shoot" vs. "shot"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/), ["Did see" vs. "saw"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30686/)  
> [“I understand you” vs. “I do understand you”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42138/)  
> [“I play” vs. “I do play”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/), [Difference between "does have" and "has"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64487/). [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RegDwighт Sorry, I did not know http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *do* form contrasts with a previous statement:

> "You could use *canvas*, but not all browsers support it".
>
> "Which browsers do support it?"

It's not restricted to the interrogative. It's one case of [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support).