# Is 'who did see you?' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, auxiliary-verbs

I realise 'who saw you' is probably more common, but is 'who did see you' wrong? This is with respect to why who-questions don't need 'do'-support as an aux verb.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of ['Which browsers do support this?' or 'Which browsers do support this?'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103214/which-browsers-do-support-this-or-which-browsers-support-this/103215#103215), itself closed as a duplicate. 'Who _did_ see you?' is a marked emphatic form, used following a statement eg by the addressee that someone _had_ seen them. It wouldn't be used as a mere replacement for 'Who saw you?'

Comment: I agree with the comment of @EdwinAshworth, and I'd add that this emphatic use of "did" would be likely to occur after negative statements. If you say "I was seen" but then you say  "Alice didn't see me" and "Bob didn't see me" and "Charlie didn't see me" then I'd be inclined to aak "Well, who did see you?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Word order with question word as subject** (from ***PEU by Michael Swan***):

When *who, which, what or whose* is the subject (or part of the subject), the question word comes before the verb, and *do* cannot normally be used.

Examples:

*Who left the door open?* ( NOT Who did leave...?)

*Which type of battery lasts longest?* (NOT Which type of battery does last longest?)

What happened? (NOT What did happen?)

**But *do* can be used after a subject question word for emphasis, to insist on an answer.**

*Well, tell us - what did happen when your father found you?*

Answer (score -1):

> Who saw you?

and

> Who did you see?

mean completely different things.

In *Who saw you?*, *who* is the subject of the sentence, so the word *who* is in the nominative case.

In *Who did you see?*, *who* is actually the direct object of the sentence, so *who* is in the accusative case. You can understand this better if you convert the sentence like this:

> You saw who?

One more thing worth telling: in *Who did you see?*, *who* is used in an informal manner, because the right form of the word *who* in the accusative case in formal English is *whom*.

So you sentence must actually be like this:

> Whom did you see?

Comment: Actually it was 'who did see you'

Comment: _Who did see you?_ is nothing more than a more emphatic way of saying _Who saw you?_

Comment: are you sure? I thought 'who did see you' was grammatically incorrect, as who is the subject? Not sure exactly why, but I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Yes, I am very sure.

Comment: I expect most people to understand "who saw you" as "by whom were you seen" in normal use.